# Best way to handle a wholesale marketplace product structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a marketplace that has a lot of creators. Currently I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to structure products.

Products have different sizes and colors which could also have a different price, stock availability. When you place an order on the marketplace you define the quantity of each item. IE: 3 red small, 4 red large or 2 blue small.

Not sure if I'm making any sense but if I am does anyone know how to best handle this?

Comment: Do products belong to a creator?

Comment: Yes they do. Creators upload their products to our marketplace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple suggestion to get you started:

#### Marketplace `has_many` Creators

Creator `belongs_to` Marketplace

#### Marketplace `has_many` customers

Customer `belongs_to` Marketplace

#### Creator `has_many` Products

Product `belongs_to` Creator

#### Customer `has_many` Orders

Order `belongs_to` Customer

#### Order `has_many` Products

Product `has_many` Orders (will need a join table here)

---

Product has `color` and `size` properties. Marketplace is responsible for knowing the `available_quantity` of a product. You'll probably need some through associations as well.

Hope it helps.